# How to send selected item on a json listview to another activity?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have used some code online to parse JSON to a listview in android. Now, I want by clicking on any item on listview to send the data in the clicked row to another activity. Tried other solutions but didn't work.

What I am working on is sending a quote and its author to another activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ListView lv;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();


}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Json Data is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chefk5/b2a6b17037e989b902834a70cc9b4ce7/raw/667f7fe8aa74cea7e54dfb69a0d2015f7b934f0d/quotes.json";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("quotes");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String quote = c.getString("quote");
                  String name = c.getString("name");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("quote", quote);
                    contact.put("name", name);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "quote","name"},
                new int[]{R.id.email,R.id.mobile});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this in onPostExecute

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "quote","name"},
                new int[]{R.id.email,R.id.mobile});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String quete = contactList.get(i).getQuete();
                String name = contactList.get(i).getName();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("QUETE", quete);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

now in your OtherActivity, put the following line of code in OnCreate() methode

```
String name = getIntent().getExtraString("NAME");
String quete = getIntent().getExtraString("QUETE");
```

thats all :)

Comment: from where I can get getQuete() and getName() ?